# Adding facebook SDK to Xcode project throws exit code 1 error

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0, xcode9

I have looked at all the questions in stackoverflow regarding this question. Still no luck.

When I add Facebook SDK to my Xcode project, it throws this error: "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". This error goes away if I delete the facebook SDK.How do I fix this? my current xcode version 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve this issue is by adding through pods.

Pods I used:

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'